# Rails: test a callback locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

In a rails app I capture a callback from an api. I get a 200 ok response but there is some sort of error in my controller code. I have the full callback and I want to test this locally. Is there a way I can send it to my app on localhost?

Comment: Do you want to test it manually or using something like rspec/capybara?

Comment: manually would be preferred

Comment: u can try with curl command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using curl in the terminal.
These are some you can try out.

```
# get
curl http://localhost:3000/posts

# post
curl --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/posts' \
--data 'title=fake_title&content=fake_content'

# put
curl --request PUT 'http://localhost:3000/posts/1'\
--data 'title=fake_title&content=fake_content'

# delete
curl --request DELETE 'http://localhost:3000/posts/1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like [Hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it/) to make the HTTP request to your app.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me to test API's is using postman google chrome app. It's useful for creating as well as handling different API requests.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

In this app you can create your different url calls to your server, and you can customize the parameters as well as the header of the call to the server.